# How to force a crash in C, is dereferencing a null pointer a (fairly) portable way?

Tags: c

I'm writing my own test-runner for my current project. One feature (that's probably quite common with test-runners) is that every testcase is executed in a child process, so the test-runner can properly detect and report a crashing testcase.

I want to also test the test-runner itself, therefore one testcase has to force a crash. I know "crashing" is not covered by the C standard and just *might* happen as a result of undefined behavior. So this question is more about the behavior of real-world implementations.

My first attempt was to just dereference a *null-pointer*:

```
int c = *((int *)0);
```

This worked in a debug build on GNU/Linux and Windows, but failed to crash in a release build because the unused variable `c` was optimized out, so I added

```
printf("%d", c); // to prevent optimizing away the crash
```

and thought I was settled. However, trying my code with `clang` instead of `gcc` revealed a surprise during compilation:

```
   [CC]   obj/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/release/src/test/test/test_s.o
src/test/test/test.c:34:13: warning: indirection of non-volatile null pointer
      will be deleted, not trap [-Wnull-dereference]
    int c = *((int *)0);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
src/test/test/test.c:34:13: note: consider using __builtin_trap() or qualifying
  pointer with 'volatile'
1 warning generated.
```

And indeed, the `clang`-compiled testcase didn't crash.

So, I followed the advice of the warning and now my testcase looks like this:

```c
PT_TESTMETHOD(test_expected_crash)
{
    PT_Test_expectCrash();

    // crash intentionally
    int *volatile nptr = 0;
    int c = *nptr;
    printf("%d", c); // to prevent optimizing away the crash
}
```

This solved my immediate problem, the testcase "works" (aka crashes) with both `gcc` and `clang`.

I guess because dereferencing the null pointer is undefined behavior, `clang` is free to compile my first code into something that doesn't crash. The `volatile` qualifier removes the ability to be sure at compile time that this really will dereference null.

Now my questions are:

- Does this final code guarantee the null dereference actually happens at runtime?
- Is dereferencing null indeed a fairly portable way for crashing on most platforms?

Comment: what about sending a SIGSEGV signal? (only on Linux/Unix though)

Comment: (and also on MinGW)

Comment: Offtopic: why do you want your code to crash? It is hard for me to imagine a specification that requires a program to crash under specific circumstances. And you have `exit(not null)` for "exit program with error".

Comment: @deniss the specification I want to test is *the test runner correctly handles and reports a crashing test case*. For testing this, I need something "similar enough" to a real crash. `abort()` seems to be close enough: the process is killed by a signal (at least on \*nix) and doesn't do any cleanup. The reason for the existence of `PT_Test_expectCrash()` is **only** this testing of the tesrunner itself. Of course I have never any specification requiring a crash.

Comment: @deniss He's doing a very smart and responsible thing: he's testing his test case. "It's hard to imagine a specification that requires a car to crash under specific circumstances" -- unless you're the engineer making sure that the air bags or other safety features work properly when they're needed.

Comment: @Steve Summit, Felix Palmen, thanks, I got it. In the car analogy, you're testing that your test stand is accelerating your car into a wall fast enough to cause a crash.

Comment: @deniss this analogy has it's weaknesses, I'd have to say "no, I just want to test that my *test stand* gives the correct measurement results even if the car unexpectedly explodes in flames" or something like that. But I guess the intention is clear now. :)

Comment: NULL pointer derefence is Undefined Behavior. So even if the compiler doesn't optimize it out, it might not cause a crash. I can imagine a system where address 0 is mapped (but not to be used in C).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya `NULL`/`0` as a pointer value doesn't necessarily mean a 0 representation, so a system where an all-bits-zero pointer would be valid would have to provide an alternative way to write it for strict conformance. `NULL`/`0` is guaranteed to be an invalid pointer value. But you're of course correct that a *crash* is **not** guaranteed. I was asking for a "fairly portable" way back then. My current solution accounts for this by using `abort()` as a last fallback :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, agreed! Null derefence can be said to be "fairly" portable (ignoring the smart compilers). But `abort` seems to be best option out there.  About the Microsoft runtime, this seems to be the first time some one has complained about good error messages :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer refering to `abort()` was great, I really didn't think of that and it's indeed a perfectly portable way of forcing an *abnormal program termination*.

Trying it with my code, I came across `msvcrt` (Microsoft's C runtime) implements `abort()` in a special chatty way, it outputs the following to `stderr`:

> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.

That's not so nice, at least it unnecessarily clutters the output of a complete test run. So I had a look at `__builtin_trap()` that's also referenced in `clang`'s warning. It turns out this gives me exactly what I was looking for:

> LLVM code generator translates __builtin_trap() to a trap instruction if it is supported by the target ISA. Otherwise, the builtin is translated into a call to abort.

It's also available in `gcc` starting with version 4.2.4:

> This function causes the program to exit abnormally. GCC implements this function by using a target-dependent mechanism (such as intentionally executing an illegal instruction) or by calling abort.

As this does something similar to a real crash, I prefer it over a simple `abort()`. For the fallback, it's still an option trying to do your own illegal operation like the null pointer dereference, but just add a call to `abort()` in case the program somehow makes it there without crashing.

So, all in all, the solution looks like this, testing for a minimum GCC version and using the much more handy `__has_builtin()` macro provided by clang:

```
#undef HAVE_BUILTIN_TRAP
#ifdef __GNUC__
#  define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 \
    + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#  if GCC_VERSION > 40203
#    define HAVE_BUILTIN_TRAP
#  endif
#else
#  ifdef __has_builtin
#    if __has_builtin(__builtin_trap)
#      define HAVE_BUILTIN_TRAP
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_BUILTIN_TRAP
#  define crashMe() __builtin_trap()
#else
#  include <stdio.h>
#  define crashMe() do { \
    int *volatile iptr = 0; \
    int i = *iptr; \
    printf("%d", i); \
    abort(); } while (0)
#endif

// [...]

PT_TESTMETHOD(test_expected_crash)
{
    PT_Test_expectCrash();

    // crash intentionally
    crashMe();
}
```

Comment: in a test I wouldn't generally be worried about chattiness. If a program has gone the route of undefined behaviour that tends to result in crashes, it could output all sorts of rubbish.

Comment: @TomTanner the chatty output was just a tiny nuisance (and it reminds me my test runner still needs capturing `stdout` and `stderr` -> TODO). What I found looking for `__builtin_trap()` seemed nevertheless *better* because it's even more similar to a real "crash" than `abort()`.

Comment: agreed, but i wouldn't make the effort to avoid the output from abort if builtin_trap isn't available.

Comment: Thanks for the `__builtin_trap()` reference. Was looking for a way to test my `HardFault_Handler()` on an ARM Cortex microcontroller, and this works great!

Answer (score 18):

I wouldn't rely on that method as being robust if I were you.

Can't you use `abort()`, which is part of the C standard and is guaranteed to cause an abnormal program termination event?

Comment: So simple! This actually works perfectly on GNU/Linux and cross-compiled with MinGW in wine, so I assume it will work on the real Windows as well, thanks!

Comment: revisiting this because of an unfortunate implementation of `abort()` in `msvcrt`, see my own answer. Still this was a really good hint, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

you can write memory instead of reading it.

```
*((int *)0) = 0;
```

Comment: Sure, thanks for the suggestion! But it would leave me with the same doubts (an "intelligent" compiler could detect the undefined behavior and decide to compile this into something "safe" in an attempt of being helpful).

Answer (score 2):

No, dereferencing a NULL pointer is not a portable way of crashing a program.  It is undefined behavior, which means just that, you have no guarantees what will happen.

As it happen, for the most part under any of the three main OS's used today on desktop computers, that being MacOS, Linux and Windows NT (*) dereferencing a NULL pointer will immediately crash your program.

That said: "The worst possible result of undefined behavior is for it to do what you were expecting."

I purposely put a star beside Windows NT, because under Windows 95/98/ME, I can craft a program that has the following source:

```
int main()
{
    int *pointer = NULL;
    int i = *pointer;
    return 0;
}
```

that will run without crashing.  Compile it as a TINY mode .COM files under 16 bit DOS, and you'll be just fine.

Ditto running the same source with just about any C compiler under CP/M.

Ditto running that on some embedded systems.  I've not tested it on an Arduino, but I would not want to bet either way on the outcome.  I do know for certain that were a C compiler available for the 8051 systems I cut my teeth on, that program would run fine on those.

Comment: This is interesting extra info, thanks! But note "portable" isn't the same as "well-defined" ;) So, good to have some examples where crashing won't happen.

Comment: @FelixPalmen True, portable and well-defined are not the same.  However I would say that in order to be portable, something must be well defined.  Therefore anything that is not well defined (i.e. undefined in C) is implicitly non-portable.

Comment: which is the strictest possible definition of "portable" and would in this case mean: It's impossible to simulate a crash, because crashing isn't mentioned anywhere in the standard ;) Your examples why a null dereference doesn't work are good, therefore I already upvoted. But I'm still happy with the solution I finally came up with (with the help of another answer here) -- I'd say it's "portable", not universally of course, but to a "reasonable" number of platforms/compilers :)

Answer (score 0):

The program below should work. It might cause some collateral damage, though.

---

```
#include <string.h>

void crashme( char *str)
{
char *omg;

for(omg=strtok(str, "" ); omg ; omg=strtok(NULL, "") ) {
        strcat(omg , "wtf");
        }
*omg =0; // always NUL-terminate a NULL string !!!
}

int main(void)
{
char buff[20];
// crashme( "WTF" );    // works!
// crashme( NULL );     // works, too
crashme( buff );        // Maybe a bit too slow ...
return 0;
}
```