# Why didn't the program crash?

Tags: c, arrays, crash

I'm running these code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Crash(char * cData){
    cData[2] = 100;
}

int main() {
    char cData[2] = {1,2};
    Crash(&cData[0]);
    printf("%d\n",cData[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the program to crash since `cData[2] = 100;`(of Crash()) will change the return address of Crash function. I believe that the memory position right next to cData[1](of main()) keeps the return address of Crash function. So after the Crash function finished execution, it will take the value in the return address(which is 100 now) and continue to execute other code. So shouldn't doing so suppose to cause the program to crash?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  In other words, anything can happen, including *appearing* to work.

Comment: are you sure that's where the return address is?

Comment: Code broke the rules and did not get caught - this time.

Comment: C does not stipulate under what the conditions the program will crash.

Comment: In simple terms, you are not supposed to dereference / write beyond the end of space (array) that you own.

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44215510/2371524) (but **not** a dupe, showing it only to demonstrate it's not even a simple thing to have a **sure** crash, although it's very simple to have it accidentally ... Disclaimer: my own question)

Comment: @babon OP knows that, it is not what was asked.

Comment: @yano: according to this image https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Call-stack-layout.svg/2000px-Call-stack-layout.svg.png then I was wrong. Still, according to the pic, next to the cData(of main()) is the Crash's parameter. So if I want to reach the Crash address, I'll have to plus 260144641 since pointer takes 4 byte... Oh, I tried and successed to crash the app with cData[260144641] = 100;. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @TrươngVănHọc I'm certainly no expert, surely there's nothing _wrong_ about that image. You'll have to look at the assembly to see what's happening; ABI for your system is probably also a factor. Perhaps there's more space being allocated than you expect, some other things could be getting pushed onto the stack. As already mentioned this is undefined behavior for `c`, so only the assembly code will tell you what's happening. `cData[bigNumber]` segfaults because you're accessing memory outside of your process space, not b/c you're overwriting the return address.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the details from your most recent comment.  They should be part of the question itself, not down here in the comments, where they won't be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior, which can be anything, including no crash at all and even expected behavior.

In your particular case, there is a chance the array `char cData[2] = {1,2};` occupies space on the stack that is padded with 2 extra bytes before other important pieces of information such as the return address or the saved stack frame pointer. Modifying one of these bytes would have no noticeable effect.  Try modifying `cData[4]` or `cData[8]`, etc. but don't blame me for undesirable side effects.

Comment: I did and the app works fine. Maybe, the space next to cData[1](of main()) is space for Crash argument which is a pointer(4 bytes). So in order to reach the return address which locates next to the argumeng space, I'll have to skip the argument space via the array index which requires me to plus 128^4. That's just my guess

Comment: @TrươngVănHọc: try `memset(cData, 0, size)` with larger values of `size` and find the sweet spot with dichotomy.